# declare -x messages appear in my terminal. How can I get rid of it?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

```
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-qoybJQ/Render"
declare -x Apple_Ubiquity_Message="/tmp/launch-DWchNf/Apple_Ubiquity_Message"
declare -x COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
declare -x DISPLAY="/tmp/launch-zF43Un/org.x:0"
[...]
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/43/z74xnym15tg55c3kyl0c05340000gn/T/"
declare -x USER="reshad"
declare -x __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0:0"
```

These messages appear in Terminal, how can I get rid of them?

---

Here's my whole bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/bin:$PATH

# Aliases
alias apache="sudo apachectl restart"
alias httpd.conf="mate /etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
alias php.ini="mate /etc/php.ini"
alias bash_profile="mate ~/.bash_profile"
alias reload="source ~/.bash_profile"
alias vhosts.conf="mate /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
alias vhost="mate /etc/apache2/vhost"
alias hosts="mate /etc/hosts"
alias php.ini="mate /etc/php.ini"
alias mysql="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql"
alias mysqladmin="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin"
alias cms="cd ~/Sites/cms"
alias webapps="cd ~/Sites/webapps"
alias zf="/Library/PHP/Zend/bin/zf.sh"
alias mysqld="mysql -uroot -p"
alias reload= "source .bash_profile"

# Git
alias gst="git status"
alias gl="git pull"
alias gp="git push"
alias gd="git diff | mate"
alias gc="git commit -v"
alias gca="git commit -v -a"
alias gb="git branch"
alias gba="git branch -a"

# SublimeText
export SUBLIME_HOME="/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app"
export PATH="$PATH:$SUBLIME_HOME/Contents/SharedSupport/bin"

# MySQL
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/bin"
source ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Comment: Do they appear in each new tab you create in Terminal? Do you have installed any software (or done any other changes) lately?

Comment: Yes it does, it appears in every new tab. Lately I installed ipython, ipython notebook and created a virtual machine deleting the existing one.

Comment: Well, one of the installs messed up your .bashrc/.alias/.profile

Comment: Heres what I have in my bash profile:

Comment: Heres what I have in my bash profile:

export
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/bin:$PATH
# SublimeText
export SUBLIME_HOME="/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app"
export PATH=$PATH:$SUBLIME_HOME/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
# MySQL
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/bin
#source ~/.git-completion.bash

Comment: Can you do `mv ~/.bash_profile ~/bash_profile`, then open a new tab to see if the problem still occurs? Afterwards (irregardless of whether it occurs) do `mv ~/bash_profile ~/.bash_profile` to reverse.

Comment: By doing the first step (mv ~/.bash_profile ~/bash_profile), the declare -x messages doesn't occur. But then non of my alias works. Then I did the second step (mv ~/bash_profile ~/.bash_profile) and the messages come again.

Comment: Can you please add the content of your .alias file to the question (you can edit the question text yourself) and also verify that the .bash_profile I pasted yesterday is correct? The lines you posted don't create any aliases so we are probably missing something.

Comment: Did you mean all the alias I have in my ~/bash_profile? I don't know what you mean by .alias file.

Comment: The whole .bash_profile then. Something in there is causing the declare commands to appear in the output. There is no way to identify the problem without access to the whole file.

Comment: Added my whole bash_profile

Comment: Delete the second alias definition for reload (which is syntactically wrong anyway) and try again. If this doesn't solve the issue, put a # in front of the last line (git completion) and try again.

Comment: Did all the steps. Still getting the messages.

Comment: Comment out the first line then, maybe your PATH contains blanks before .bash_profile is even read. Then open a new tab again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6502/discussion-between-patrix-and-user35124)

Comment: commenting out the first line didn't make any change.

Comment: Got rid of it. There was a blank space in my export path in first line. Thanks for being there with me and helping all the way.

Comment: Reshad, I recommend you add this as an answer, so people will notice.  This effected me in the same way, I had newlines after some export statements, and it caused the output issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different Bash script files that get executed before and after your .bash_profile file is executed. This [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) page explains all the various Bash script files that get executed upon starting up a Bash shell.

p.s. Keep in mind that any one of those files could include commands to load/execute yet another file.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling to find the issue between my .bash_profile and .aliases files I notices that there was a line that had an "enter" space between the "export" and the variable supposed to be exposed.

[image]

Removing the "enter" and restarting the shell or running "source .bash_profile" solved my issue.

Comment: It’s not an “Enter.”  It’s called a an *EOL* or *End of Line* character.